# Saltstack: (boto_secgroup) Add a rule that allows ALL TRAFFIC to a sec group

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, salt-stack, ec2-api-tools, amazon-ec2

[using salt --version: 2015.5.0] I want to add a rule that allows ALL TRAFFIC from another security group

I have this in my pillar:

```
securitygroups:
    groups:
       - name: NFS
         region: us-east-1
         vpc_id: vpc-1234
         description: desc
         rules:
           - ip_protocol: -1
             from_port: -1
             to_port: -1
             ec2_group: sg123456
```

API suggests to use -1 to specify all **IpProtcol**. But I'm getting this error:

```
----------
          ID: secgroups_NFSecurityGroup
    Function: boto_secgroup.present
        Name: NFSecurityGroup
      Result: False
     Comment: An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/state.py", line 1563, in call
                  **cdata['kwargs'])
                File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/states/boto_secgroup.py", line 140, in present
                  _ret = _rules_present(name, rules, vpc_id, region, key, keyid, profile)
                File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/states/boto_secgroup.py", line 345, in _rules_present
                  to_delete, to_create = _get_rule_changes(rules, sg['rules'])
                File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/states/boto_secgroup.py", line 265, in _get_rule_changes
                  raise SaltInvocationError(msg.format(ip_protocol))
              SaltInvocationError: Invalid ip_protocol traffic specified in security group rule.
     Started: 03:09:58.163808
    Duration: 235.323 ms
```

**from_port:** -1 and **to_port:** -1 works fine if I specify an ip_protocol: icmp|tcp|udp

Answer (score 0):

I think the `-1` value for protocol only works for security groups that are part of a VPC.  For EC2-Classic I think you would have to add three separate rules, one for each protocol.

Comment: Thank you @garnaat, I added a vpc_id to the stack and it doesn't work